# How to check which user installed the package or software?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management

Multi-user system.

Fedora 12 x86_64.

All users are `sudo`ers.

Comment: If you have a date when the package was installed, you might want to check `/var/log/auth.log` for a sudo incident on that date.

Comment: Is auditing enabled?

Comment: Do you need to know for security reasons or for convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora 12 is a bit old but I think you can still do the following:

Look in `/var/log/secure` which has lines for each use of `sudo`. For example, you might find:

```
Aug 11 15:16:37 home sudo: user : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; \
 USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rpm -i /home/user/mypackage.rpm
```

List all the installation times of the rpms with:

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{name} %{version}-%{release} %{installtime:date}\n'
```

Match the time or the package name, eg:

```
mypackage 11.0.1.1056-20081001 Mon Aug 11 15:16:14 2014
```

Comment: To say F12 is 'a bit old' is an understatement.  It went out of support at the end of 2010.